# Set default value for Lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to set default value for a lookup column in schema.xml?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way you can set the default value of a look up field (Custom or OOB). You can do it programmatically.

Also check:

[Sharepoint 2010: How to set default value for a lookup column (without InfoPath forms)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32853/sharepoint-2010-how-to-set-default-value-for-a-lookup-column-without-infopath)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2008/06/19/how-to-set-the-default-value-for-a-look-up-field-for-an-item-as-it-is-being-created.aspx